# Convert excel multi header data in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

My data in excel looks like:
[image]

and I want to convert it in a pandas dataframe like:
[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: It was not my first preference to add a photo. I tried adding actual table but I did not find an easy way to create a multi header merged cell table in the comments section. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: My experience with MultiIndex excel file is answer depends of file, so if now not working best is create excel sample (5 rows is perfect like in question), share it, so possible answerer can test with file with same real structure. From picture also from text not 100% sure if file has same content (index and MultiIndex is important for test).

Answer (score 1):

Create MulitIndex in columns and in index:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, index_cols=[0,1,2], header=[0,1])

#verify MultiIndex
print (df.index)
MultiIndex([(    'Pencil', 'A01',   'Red'),
            (       'Pen', 'A02',  'Blue'),
            ('Toothbrush', 'B01', 'Green')],
           names=['ProductName', 'ProductCode', 'Color'])

#verify MultiIndex
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('Jan-22', 'Supplier1'),
            ('Jan-22', 'Supplier2'),
            ('Jan-22',     'Total'),
            ('Feb-22',  'Supplie1'),
            ('Feb-22', 'Supplier2'),
            ('Feb-22',     'Total')],
           )
```

Then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with remove columns `Total`:

```
df = (df.drop('Total', axis=1, level=1)
        .rename_axis(['Date','SupplierName'], axis=1)
        .stack([0,1])
        .reset_index(name='Volumes'))
```